# Error while cross-compiling chromium for ARM from x_64

Tags: linux, arm, chromium

I am trying to build chromium from source code following instructions at
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md

I have successfully built and tested chromium for amd device, Now I am trying to cross-compile it for arm device, However when I set the flag

> target_cpu = "arm"
> using
> gn gen out/Debug --args='target_cpu="arm"'
> I get the following error

```
ERROR at //build/config/linux/atk/BUILD.gn:13:1 (//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x86_v8_arm): Assertion failed.
assert(current_toolchain == default_toolchain)
^-----
See //ui/accessibility/BUILD.gn:294:20: which caused the file to be included.
      configs += [ "//build/config/linux/atk" ]
```

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/chromium_arm.md ?

Comment: yes, After I followed those instructions, I get the error. ASAIK, it only asks to run ./build/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-sysroot.py --arch=arm apart from steps i mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue where I tried building chromium on my Linux x64 server for an ARM based device, I was able to get past the issue by commenting the **assert** function out (as the function assert is usually for sanity checking based on my understanding). You can achieve this by modifying the file **build/config/linux/atk/BUILD.gn** and adding a **#** to the following code **assert(current_toolchain == default_toolchain)**.

I followed the guidance on the webpage suggested by Asesh (followed Recipe 2) but the issue we are facing is to do with different current_toolchain and default_toolchain being set and would cause **assert()** to fail, the instructions given on the webpage doesn't seem to relate to out problem.(https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/chromium_arm.md)

To explain why I commented out the assert() code, reading https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration I found the following section: [Snip of section "Overriding the CPU architecture"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJPgQ.png).

As we both are configuring **target_cpu="arm"**, this should be enough to configure and build chromium for our ARM devices (this would cause **current_toolchain** to be set to a different toolchain then **default_toolchain**, hence why **assert()** is giving us this error).

After commenting out the assert() I was successfully able to run **gn gen out/xxx**, **gn args out/xxx** and run **autoninja** to build chromium.

Comment: Nicely put. I actually used to this to resolve the problem but forgot to mention here. Thanks for putting it this elegantly

Comment: Anytime @AbhishekAnand, glad to hear you got this resolved. Hopefully this will help someone else down the line.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in Chromium:

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/3074662

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While I do see clear information on recently fixed issues as a useful answer I would like this post better if it would identify the release with the solution (e.g. by release date, or version number, ....). That would improve the long term useability of this answer. Note that information only available via a link is not considered part of an answer on StackOverflow.